# Screen Sharing safari

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webrtc, get-display-media

Screen Share isn't working on Safari but it's working okay on Chrome, Edge and Opera.
I get error getdisplaymedia must be called from a user gesture handler

```
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
        video: true
      });
```

I want to allow user to share screen

Comment: What results did you get when you searched for the error "*getdisplaymedia must be called from a user gesture handler*"?